# Is Next Bad to Use if I Don't Need it?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

In `express` and `connect`, is it bad to use "next" in middleware if I do not need it? Are there any possible negative outcomes? Assume there is no middleware which will be called after this middleware, and therefore the `next` will not call anything. I know it is bad for modularity, as if you want to add a callback for another middleware it may be accidentally triggered by the `next` in this middleware. However, in this case `next` is bad for modularity anyway, as middleware often interact in unexpected ways.

As an example of an unneeded `next`, consider [the sample `MEAN.JS` stack](https://github.com/meanjs/mean), constructed by the guys who originally came up with the stack's name. It seems to have some `next` callbacks which do not ever get called. Many are in [the `users` controller](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/controllers/users/users.authentication.server.controller.js), including the `signin` function:

```
exports.signin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            res.status(400).send(info);
        } else {
            // Remove sensitive data before login
            user.password = undefined;
            user.salt = undefined;

            req.login(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                } else {
                    res.json(user);
                }
            });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

This function has a `next` callback defined. This `next` callback is then used by the `passport.authenticate()` custom middleware function as a parameter. However, this parameter is never used in the function itself. I have tried taking out the `next` definition from the function definition, as well as the custom `passport` middleware, and the route seems to still work. However, perhaps `passport` uses it in its `authenticate()` function, and leaving it out did not cause any trouble here but it may cause trouble in some cases.

I was recently looking at `passport`'s tutorials on http://passportjs.org, and I came across a function in the section on custom callbacks on [the `authenticate` page](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) that looks almost exactly like the `signin` function in `MEAN.JS`. One difference was that it actually had some `next` callbacks (for error handling), so the `next` parameter was actually useful. Is it possible that the `MEAN.JS` app took a lot of code from `passportjs.org`'s guide and changed it over time, but left in some vestigial remnants that do not do anything but were causing no harm? Or does the `next` parameter actually do something in `passport.authenticate()` that is not immediately obvious? Regardless of why this happened, **does an extra `next` parameter in `connect` middleware cause any bad side effects if it is not used?**

Comment: your example pointing to the signin function of the users controller DOES use `next`, fyi.

Comment: If there is never a case where you would want an additional middleware to be called, then the next callback need not be executed. However, it would be safer to just assume the possibility of there being such a middleware so that if one was added, it wouldn't mean trying to track down any middleware that wasn't executing the next callback.

Comment: The `passport.authenticate()` function defines it, yes, but it does not *use* it. I tried to make that clear, but couldn't. I will try again.

Comment: no, it doesn't define it, it uses it. `passport.authenticate('local', function () {...})(req, res, next)` What this does is it executes passport.authenticate, which returns a function that is then executed with `req`, `res`, and `next`. Similar to an IIFE. `(function(){})` returns a function, and `(function(a){})(window)` executes the function with `window`.

Comment: @KevinB, I could not figure out a way to say that coherently, but I understand your point. Regardless, the `authenticate` function itself does not use it to do any meaningful thing.

Comment: As to your 2nd comment above, are there any other consequences, besides being useless and unnecessary?

Comment: Not that i am aware of, as long as the request has already ended so that the client doesn't end up with a timeout.

Comment: Can you make that an answer? Also, check my updated question; does it &/or my comments clear up your confusion?

Comment: I would, but... i'm not absolutely sure it is correct, i've only been using express for a few months now. I just haven't observed any side effects myself.

Comment: I know why they included it in passport, i just don't know if there are any side effects from not including it in your own code that only you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing middleware, the `next` parameter is optional. It's purpose is so that the next middleware in the chain will be called. If you want the current middleware to be the last one called for a given request, not executing the `next` parameter will accomplish that. This is fine for code that you write for yourself, but it's typically better to always execute the `next` parameter in middleware that may be used elsewhere because you don't know what else they could be adding.

For example, maybe you wanted to add some kind of logging that happens after a request is completed. If your middleware that runs before the logging middleware doesn't execute `next`, it won't be logged.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware

Not executing `next` will simply not start the next middleware. There are no other side effects of not executing it other than those caused by not moving to the next middleware (for example, if the response hasn't ended yet, not calling `next` will result in a timeout.)

Comment: I thought you said you didn't want to answer because you weren't sure if this was the answer. Does this mean you did some research?

Comment: Yes, and it confirmed my findings. the express docs, specifically the portion linked in my answer

Comment: OK, thank you. I thought this was the case, but I wanted to be sure, which is why I asked here.

Comment: If you don't call `next()`, how does express know that middleware is done and it can now process the route?

Comment: depends on if the middleware is application level or router level, right?

Comment: And whether it's applied before the router or after.